# Accessing Relationships in Firebase

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase

I've got some data my in Firebase that simply looks like this:

```
services: {
  service1: {
    name: "Hernia Repair"
  },
  service2: { ... },
  service3: { ... }
},
providerInService: {
  service1: {
    provider1: true,
    provider2: true
  },
  service2: { ... },
  service3: { ... }
},
providers: {
  provider1: {
    name: 'The Whittington Hospital'
  },
  provider2: { ... },
  provider3: { ... }
}
```

I'm trying to print my list of `services` to the page with an ng-repeat, while also printing the available providers that are attached to that service in the `providerInService` object.

I'm using the `.on` listener to push the list of `services` from Firebase to `$scope.services`:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://testnews.firebaseio.com");
var servicesRef = ref.child('services');

$scope.services = [];

servicesRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.services.push(snap.val());
  });
});
```

And I'm repeating the services on my page like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="service in services">
  <h3>{{ service.name }}</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>related provider</li>
    <li>related provider</li>
    <li>related provider</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Though, I'm stuck at how to print the list of related providers as they're not part of the `services` tree.

Do I have to use the SERVICE_ID to lookup the matching SERVICE_ID in `providerInService`, then loop through the matching object to obtain the PROVIDER_IDs, and then loop through the `providers` object to retrieve the `name`?

I've never done anything as complex as this. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Elastic search could maybe be a little help here, joins are kind of tricky to handle in Firebase. https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html

Comment: Please add the minimal code to show what you already have, so that we have something to go on. To give some idea why we need that: the tags suggest that you're **not** using AngularFire, which the code could easily help us verify. I will vote to close, until you add code (at which case I'll gladly retract the vote).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated my question. Hopefully the extra code I've added helps give the question more context. And no, I'm not using AngularFire currently.

Comment: Also, there are [so many questions about joins](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+join) I can't decide which to mark this as a duplicate of. Here are some great fiddles to get you started: [simple merge](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/uoe5yt8x/) [$extend](http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/6dzys/)

Comment: Also, we released [firebase-util](http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/#/) yesterday, which has some great tools for [normalizing records](http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/#/toolbox/NormalizedCollection/)